# Ajax doing everything but appending HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Basic "Load More on Scroll" AJAX function, console shows HTML being sent back from the request, but nothing is rendered. I must be overlooking something very simple.

```js
$(window).scroll(function()
{
   if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="postswrapper">
 <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="color: #FFF;">
  <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

On scroll, the loader gets hidden as requested, but no HTML is brought back from loader.php. Loading loader.php by itself gives the correct HTML, though, so I'm certain the problem is with the AJAX.

requested return HTML

```html
<td>
  <div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image:url('./img/FOLIO/JDOUBLE - THE DROP 1.jpg');" name="counter1 row6"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/JDOUBLE - THE DROP 1.jpg" data-lightbox="JDOUBLE - "THE DROP"" data-title="JDouble - The Drop (2014)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>JDOUBLE - "THE DROP" <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2014</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td><div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image: url('./img/FOLIO/CEDEK - ACTION v8.jpg');" name="counter2 row5"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/CEDEK - ACTION v8.jpg" data-lightbox="CEDEK - "ACTION REMIX"" data-title="Cedek & Niko Javan - Action Remix (2015)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>CEDEK - "ACTION REMIX" <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2015</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td><div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image: url('./img/FOLIO/DEAUX APRIL 1 - UNION.jpg');" name="counter3 row4"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/DEAUX APRIL 1 - UNION.jpg" data-lightbox="EVENT FLYER" data-title="Event Flyer (2015)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>EVENT FLYER <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2015</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td width="20%"><div class="spacer20"></div></td></tr><tr><td width="20%"><div class="spacer20"></div></td><td><div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image: url('./img/FOLIO/LINZ PRAG - HIGH UP.jpg');" name="counter1 row3"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/LINZ PRAG - HIGH UP.jpg" data-lightbox="LINZ PRAG - "HIGH UP"" data-title="Linz Prag - High Up (2014)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>LINZ PRAG - "HIGH UP" <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2014</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td><div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image: url('./img/FOLIO/BAZAAR v5.jpg');" name="counter2 row2"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/BAZAAR v5.jpg" data-lightbox=""BAZAAR"" data-title="HPNTK & LEViTATE - Bazaar (2015)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>"BAZAAR" <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2015</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td><div class="foliocontainer" style="background-image: url('./img/FOLIO/ATLFOREVER4-V5.jpg');" name="counter3 row1"><ul class="overlaycontainer"><li><a href="./img/FOLIO/ATLFOREVER4-V5.jpg" data-lightbox=""ATLANTA FOREVER 4" CONCEPT ART " data-title="Atlanta Forever 4 Concept Art (2014)"><span class="textoverlay"><span>"ATLANTA FOREVER 4" CONCEPT ART  <br /><center><span style="font-size: 18px;">2014</span></center></span></span></a></li></ul></div></td><td width="20%"><div class="spacer20"></div></td></tr><tr><td width="20%"><div class="spacer20"></div></td>
```

Comment: `"no HTML is brought back from loader.php"` - Then what *does* come back?  When you debug this in your web browser, what is the server's response to the AJAX request?  What is in the `html` variable?  Where specifically does this fail?

Comment: Yeah, just `console.log(html);` and see what it spits out. Make sure to also be echoing/including/redirecting in your php file.

Comment: Console spits back the correct HTML.

Comment: Hmm, can you post the HTML you are getting? Or at least a bit of it (if it's a lot). As in, post the exact value of what `html` contains.

Comment: @David dam bruh thats a lot of questions

Comment: Perhaps your html contains invalid tags that cause your content to not display. You can also check with the DOM inspector to see if there's anything inside of your `postswrapper` after appending. Invalid tags, or perhaps some `display: none` thrown in there somewhere?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: That's how debugging works.  One observes the behavior of the code and gathers information.  It's a lot more effective than just asking the internet to guess what *might* be wrong.

Comment: @David I know bro, I was just messing with you :)

Comment: i appreciate the amount of questions @David is asking, they are critical. I have checked the HTML, but it is a replica of the HTML already being displayed (the return is just more rows of content being loaded into the main page) but I have added it to the original post anyway.

Comment: THERE WAS AN ERROR IN THE HTML. Sorry.

Comment: It's a good idea to define `dataType` in your ajax call, since otherwise you're relying on jQuery to guess.  `dataType : "html"` in this case.  I'm willing to bet even with your error this would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Error in the returned HTML. $counter was used in the main page to designate when a new row in the table should be created. Using the same variable in the external call (loader.php) would result in $counter being an incorrect value, despite it being right on the external page as a standalone. Changing the external page variable to $counter2 solved the issue.